# Matlab optimisation

Tags: matlab, optimization, bsxfun

Apologies if this is too much like a 'do my homework' question.  I am a bit stuck and this is my go to place.  This is not code I wrote, but I am now maintaining it.

I have a tool that runs for around 8 hours on a bad day.  I profiled it today.  91.4% of runtime is in one subfunction, and within that 70% of the time is spent on this one line of code. This is getting called effectively 60000 times in the profiled run due to being inside 3-4 nested for loops (unavoidable)

```
    testincrease = ones(183,3021)*.02;
    cRange = (0:177)'; %fix broken syntax highlighting --> '
    pRate = ones(183,3021)*.02;
    lengthA = 0;
    lengthP = 178;
    nSim = 3021;

    tic
    for i  = 1:100
    v_F = @(adj_N,adj_I) (((1+ adj_I+ testincrease(cRange+1,:))./(1 + adj_N + pRate(cRange+1,:))).^...
                repmat([cRange+0.5],[1 nSim]))...
                ./ ...
                (repmat(((1+adj_I+testincrease(lengthA+1,:))./(1 + adj_N+ pRate(lengthA+1,:))), [lengthP 1]).^...
                repmat([repmat(cRange(1), [lengthP 1])], [1 nSim]));
    v=v_F(0,0);
    end
    toc
```

Current Ideas:

I think that perhaps I could use bsxfun in place of repmat (and am trying that at the moment)

When cRange(1) = 0 (as it did in one part of my test data - the part I have put here) the second half is simply dividing by 1 - an expensive and meaningless calculation.  So I want to use 'if' clauses around this to avoid unnecessary calculation.

Calling another language - this would be entirely new for me.  Probably going to try it.  There is apparently easy access to java, and also creating mex files.  In the latter case I think the overhead of passing data will be to expensive unless I rewrite huge swathes of code rather than just this one line.

If you have any other thoughts I would be grateful to hear them.  If not I'll keep doing some more research.

Edit:  Just noticed that the final line of the function repmats are completely unnecessary, since you can .^ by a scalar value without needing to change it to a matrix

Secondary edit:  This is what it looks like so far. 30% savings.

```
tic
for i  = 1:100
    if cRange(1) == 0

        v_F = @(adj_N,adj_I) bsxfun(@power,((1+ adj_I+ testincrease(cRange+1,:))./(1 + adj_N + pRate(cRange+1,:))),cRange+0.5);

    else
        v_F = @(adj_N,adj_I) bsxfun(@power,((1+ adj_I+ testincrease(cRange+1,:))./(1 + adj_N + pRate(cRange+1,:))),cRange+0.5)...
            ./ ...
            (repmat(((1+adj_I+testincrease(lengthA+1,:))./(1 + adj_N+ pRate(lengthA+1,:))).^cRange(1), [lengthP 1]));

    end
    v=v_F(0,0);
end
AllChange = toc;
```

But for some reason the bsxfun change that speeds it up in 2011a slows it down in 2008 where we compile. Bugger.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith 4 million bytes = 4 MB. That is not really "huge"...

Comment: sorry my bad! long night... no sleep because of new baby... i thought it was 4GB.

Comment: What you show us has the same output in all 100 iterations of the for loop, you could cut things by a factor of 100 by changing your for loop to `for i=1:1`.  Beyond that, your nested `repmat` could be replaced by a single `repmat`, do `doc repmat` from a matlab prompt to see that you don't need a separate `repmat for each dimension.  Finally, from what you show, every time this for loop is called it gives the same answer.  Find that answer one time, hard code it in as a constant and move on.  There MUST be something else going on here you aren't showing us?

Comment: Sorry, this is a massively simplified version of what goes on - i imagined this was the simplest way to demonstrate the sort of thing I was talking about.  The inputs to this function change hugely on each iteration and it gets called 58,000 times.  However since this one line of code accounted for nearly 50% of run time simply making it faster would have a large impact.

Comment: To be clear, there are around 7000 lines of code for the complete tool. This is one line of a subfunction looped to make the timing a meaningful size

Comment: It's still not clear why you must declare a function inside a for loop. It's not hard to program one outside of one. Alternatively don't use anonymous functions. Make your own function, perhaps add a few inputs to make things smoother.

Comment: There are about 7-8 different versions of this formula, only one of which gets used in each loop.  I am not entirely sure why they were not simply 'pre-declared' and/or what need there is to use function handles at all.

That should actually save another 5% or so if I take them out of the loop.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion 1 - try rewriting code without repmat:

`repmat` makes tons of memory allocations and memory copies... so if you were to rewrite the code to be the same functionality but don't use `repmat` it might have huge speed increase. (FYI... that one line of code has 4 `repmat` function calls... one of the `repmat` calls has `repmat` INSIDE of it... that would be horribly slow.)

Suggestion 2 - try rewriting the one-liner:

rewrite this MASSIVE one-liner into multiple lines. then re-run your profiler. you will then be able to more clearly see exactly what is causing the slow down! then you can fix that bit of code. (pro tip: massive one liners are sometimes not the best thing to have in your code because of various reasons (readability, debugging, performance, etc)) – Trevor Boyd Smith 17 secs ago edit

Suggestion 3 - take advantage of parallelization:

I think most of the operations in your one line of code can be parallelized. So I suggest first trying Matlab's parallel toolboo. Then if that still isn't fast enough... try using GPU acceleration via an external third-party Matlab GPU acceleration software package like [Jacket](http://www.accelereyes.com/products/jacket).

---

(Disclaimer: These are general tips... I haven't tried any of these yet myself... but I will when I get the time.)

Comment: I have added my 'latest' version to the OP.  A bit of this taken into account.  Will try and profile a more broken down version as you suggested - good idea!

Comment: FYI, usually i don't post without trying these things myself... but sometimes it is good to give ideas... especially if someone else can try out the ideas before me.